# What is this erosion on 5 yr old water heater?

Tags: water, heater, rust

What is this rust erosion on 5yr old water heater? We have lars mascot boiler of that means anything.

[image: erosion]

Comment: @crip659, Make that an answer.

Comment: it is rust, not erosion

Answer (score 1):

Usually for that to happen you need a leak to allow water on surface.

It looks like you have two leaks. One at/near the hose and one from the white pipe or above the white pipe(unseen).

I think not the white pipe itself, but just above where the small light brown circle in the big rust stain is. From the plastic cap just to the left bottom of the white plastic cap.